# Facebook deep linking conflict on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, conflict, deep-linking

I have two iOS apps that uses the same Facebook app to perform a Facebook Connect. One app must use deep linking, there other shouldn't. The problem is I don't how to handle the shouldn't case.

I have tried to use the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method and return NO when the app shouldn't use deep linking but it does not seem to work.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

At least you could try crash your app which you don't want to handle url. (e.g. throw an exception)

Have you tried to specify two different URL Scheme Suffixes?

Comment: Yes I did try to use two different URL scheme suffixes. This works fine for the SSO but is not implemented for deep linking.

Comment: How about open one app from another?